# Our Granite and Basalt vs. Their Granite and Basalt

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, hard-science, geology

Earth is constructed of two different rocks--continental granite and oceanic basalt.

[image]

[image]

In an alternate Earth, this is granite...

[image]

...and this is basalt.

[image]

As you can see here, the proportions of mineral composition differ from back home.  Now the question is, how will these differences affect granite and basalt's characteristics in comparison to ours?  Would this make the crust different from our own?

Comment: I'm no expert but the changes seem so small that I doubt anything important will change.

Comment: Those are oddly specific values! +1 for depth

Comment: I am afraid that just giving the relative ratio of the chemical species is not enough to answer your question. Diamond is made of 100% carbon, graphite is made of 100% carbon, are they the same?

Comment: Rocks are not only about mineral content, but also about the process. So what changes in their creation process caused changes in content?

Comment: I'd suggest that the [Earth Science](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) stack is more appropriate for this question - there's going to be geologists there.  And I'd really recommend you place those comparisons side-by-side - it's very awkward to compare with so much scrolling needed.

Comment: @L.Dutch While it is true that the atomic configuration matters for most compounds (otherwise diamond would be the same as graphite), in this particular case I'm fairly certain it does not. Rocks are not made out of one type of crystal from all constituents but a mixture of different crystals packed together, each with it's own habit, and the exact composition and arrangement already varies widely for the granite and basalt of our world. I think we can safely assume that the minerals will take on the same lattice in both worlds as many of the minerals does not have alternative habits.

Comment: Your pie charts don't use the same colors for the same minerals. That makes this question very difficult to understand. -1

Comment: Perhaps you could add these comparisons in a table below? (probably fairly easy to grab as they would have been required to create the pie charts). Also maybe a little detail on what you would like an answer to look at (could be that the composition would mean the mass of the other earth is different to ours so the gravity may be different but you might want a focus on life and how it would develop with lower amounts of potassium etc so some information on that would help).

Comment: If you change the mineral content too much, you get a different kind of rock.  You could probably find Earth rocks with similar mineral composition to your alien 'granite' and 'basalt'.  Also process matters: e.g. obsidian & basalt are (IIRC) chemically the same, but obsidian has cooled quickly to produce a glass.

Answer (score 2):

## Granite

Granite is a felsic, intrusive, igneus rock.

- Felsic means rich in minerals that form feldspar and quartz, the two
  most common minerals in the Earth's crust. The opposite of felsic
  is mafic, which are rocks that have higher concentrations of
  magnesium and iron.
- Intrusive means that it formed from magma that crystallized within
  the Earth's crust. The contrasting term is extrusive which is lava
  that reached the surface (extruded) before crystallizing.
- Igneous means of volcanic origin.

Granite is defined as a rock that has at least 20% quartz and at most 65% alkali feldspar.

Quartz is SIO$_4$. Your pie charts list 'silicon', which makes no mention of the oxygen that must be attached to it, despite using 'oxide' to refer to many of the other mineral components.

The alkali feldspars are a huge family that could include orthoclase, sanidine, microcline, and others. They generally have the form KAlSi$_3$O$_8$ or NaAlSi$_3$O$_8$ with either a monoclinic or tri-clinic crystal structure.

So your pie chart isn't quite accurate. If you broke down a granite by thermal decomposition into the constituent parts of its molecular structure-- i.e. heating the quartz and feldspar crystals until they broke apart--you would get something like 72% silica (not silicon) (Si$_2$); 14% alumina (not aluminum) Al$_2$O$_3$; 4% Potassium Oxide (K$_2$O); 3% Sodium Oxide (Na$_2$O), etc.

For your proposed changes to granite, I just don't see much of a difference. This is partially because your two pie charts are color coded differently, but so far as I can determine the only difference is that the ferrous oxide is gone. **This will have no change on the chemical or mechanical properties of granite.**

## Basalt

Basalt is an extrusive igneous rock. Its required composition is 45-55% silica and less than 10% feldspathoids; the rock must also be greater than 65% plagioclase feldspar (CaAl$_2$Si$_2$O$_8$ or NaAlSi$_3$O$_8$) where the silica is a constituent of this feldspar.

With the Basalt, you have upped the magnesium and potassium oxide content while removing the ferrous oxide. The shift to potassium oxide implies that more of the feldspar is alkali rather than plagioclase. However, without numbers it is impossible to calculate if the plagioclase concentration is low enough to make this no longer basalt. There are alkali basalts that are relatively enriched in alkali feldspars; they tend to have more titanium and iron oxides. There is a form of basalt with high magnesium content called Boninite. Since these basalts are within the range of types found on Earth, **there would be no significant differences in chemical or mechanical properties between the basalt on Earth and those on your world.**

## Conclusion

The changes you propose are not significant enough to make change the appearance or characteristics of the rocks to any but the specialist. However, it is worth noting that if you did make significant changes, you would likely no longer have a rock of the same type, since each rock is defined by its chemical composition.

Comment: I was just following the columns used in page 158 of "The Encyclopedia of Earth:  A Complete Visual Guide".